# Checkbox state Based on cell content of Datagridview Column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I had this problem on how do i make the checkbox state change when the cell content in the column 1 of my datagridview?

For example:

I have this datagridview with two columns, Column 1 and Column 2.

Column 1 - represents numbers/integer like 1 or 2
and
Column 2 - DataGridView CheckBoxColumn

Case is:

If the value of cell in Column 1 = 1, column 2 which is the DataGridView CheckBoxColumn, Checkbox state is "Checked"

If the value of cell in Column 1 = 2, column 2 which is the DataGridView CheckBoxColumn, Checkbox state is "UnChecked"

How do i do this in vb.net code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each row of the grid, then make a comparison to set the value of the `CheckBox`

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow in yourGrid.Rows
   If row.Columns("Column1").Value = 1 Then
      row.Columns("Column2").Value = True
   Else
      row.Columns("Column2").Value = False
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with an event on your cell:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Val_change(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
    Dim val As String = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
    If val = "1" Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = True
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = False
    End If
End Sud
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use  DataTable  bound to the data grid view , try to add a new expression column to the data table and bind it to the checkbox column in the DataGridView.

the new expression column can be like below

```
 Dim checkBoxColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn
 With checkBoxColumn
     .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean")
     .ColumnName = "CheckBoxColumn"
     .Expression = "IIF(Column1=1 ,True,False)"
 End With

 'add the new column to your dataTale
 myTable.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn)
```